# Printing files in.dwg format from AutoCAD

Tags: windows-8, autocad

Does anyone know if there are any drivers supported for Windows 8 to print AutoCAD 2014 .dwg files?
I am currently using KIP Plotters, but they only support till Windows 7 for now.

Any help regarding the same will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you don't have a problem with printing, but with missing drivers? Have you tried those from Win7 on Win8?

Comment: The current drivers are supported till Windows 7, So I believe they would not support Windows 8.

Comment: Try to install them. Nothing will break and there's a big chance everything will work fine. And please edit your question, as this is not related to AutoCAD at all.

Comment: Ok... Let me try that...Thanks for your advice Sir. I will keep you posted if it worked.